# Invocar a otro método luego de ingresar datos por teclado

Tags: java

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que mi método `regisDat()` se ejecute cuando capturo el primer nombre de mi metodo `regisNom()`? Actualmente al ejecutar el primer método pregunta la cantidad de pacientes que deseo capturar, pero me pide capturar los 5 de corrido y los imprime y luego ejecuta el segundo método. Me gustaría que se intercalara.

**Ejemplo de cómo se ejecuta actualmente**

Cuantos usuarios registraras : 5
Ingrese el nombre del paciente: josé
Paciente: josé
Ingrese el nombre del paciente: Pedro
Paciente: Pedro
Ingrese el nombre del paciente: Carlos
Paciente: Carlos
Ingrese el nombre del paciente: Karla
Paciente: Karla
Ingrese el nombre del paciente: Omar
Paciente: Omar

Horas de ayuno?: 8
Hace cuanto tiempo dono sangre: 70
El paciente a pasado el filtro
La muestra de sangre a sido tomada (teclee 1 = OK, 2 = NO)
El donante puede pasar a la sala de donación

Horas de ayuno?: 7
Hace cuanto tiempo dono sangre: 50
El paciente no a pasado el filtro

**Ejemplo de cómo se debería de ejecutar**

Cuantos usuarios registraras : 5
Ingrese el nombre del paciente: José
Paciente registrado: José
Horas de ayuno?: 8
Hace cuanto tiempo dono sangre: 70
El paciente a pasado el filtro
La muestra de sangre a sido tomada (teclee 1 = OK, 2 = NO)
El donante puede pasar a la sala de donación

Ingrese el nombre del paciente: Pedro
Paciente registrado: Pedro
Horas de ayuno?: 7
Hace cuanto tiempo dono sangre: 50
El paciente no ha pasado el filtro

**Este es mi código**

```
package bancosangre;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BancoSangre {
    public static void regisDat() {
        int dato1, dato2, dato3;
    
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.print("¿Horas de ayuno? (1er Paciente ):");
        dato1 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("¿Hace cuanto tiempo dono sangre?(1er Paciente):");
        dato2 = scan.nextInt();

        if (dato1 >= 8 && dato2 > 60) {
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("El 1er paciente a pasado el filtro");
            System.out.print("La muestra de sangre a sido tomada (teclee 1 = OK, 2 = NO): ");
            dato3 = scan.nextInt();

            if (dato3 == 1)   
                System.out.println("El donante puede pasar a la sala de donación");
            else if (dato3 == 2)
                System.out.println("El donante no es apto para la donación");
        } else {
            System.out.println("1er paciente no pasa el filtro");
        }
    }

    public static void regisNom() {
        int cantUsuarios, i;
        String nombre;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.print("Cantidad de personas a registrar: ");
            cantUsuarios = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
        } while (cantUsuarios > 5);

        for (i = 0; i < cantUsuarios; i++) {
            System.out.print("Ingrese el nombre del paciente: ");
            nombre = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ". Paciente: " + nombre);
        }  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        regisNom();  
        regisDat();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pues .... llamar al método cuando quieres que se ejecute. Lo que tienes no es ningún problema, el código hace exactamente lo que le pides. De hecho, por lo general el código *siempre* hace exactamente lo que le indican... es como las matemáticas, mismos valores siempre producen los mismos resultados. Si quieres que se invoquen uno tras otro, elimina la llamada a regisDat() de tu `main` y ponla dentro del bucle del otro método, y ya está! Si no, va a entrar al bucle y no va a parar hasta terminar esas órdenes, y luego seguirá con las de `regisDat`, que es exactamente lo que le indicas que haga!

Answer (score 1):

No puedes intercalar tus métodos por que al ser de tipo vid, estos se ejecutan por separado, lo que podrías realizar es unir los métodos en uno solo para que interactivo con el for que tienes para capturar el dato cantidad Usuarios, así cada vez que ingreses un nombre procederá a evaluarlo antes de pasar al siguiente paciente, el código quedaría así

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BancoSangre {

    public static void regisNom(int cantUsuarios) {
        int dato1, dato2, dato3; 
        String nombre; 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < cantUsuarios; i++) {
            System.out.print("Ingrese el nombre del paciente: ");
            nombre = scan.next();
            System.out.println((i + 1) + ". Paciente: " + nombre);
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
            System.out.print("¿Horas de ayuno? (1er Paciente ):");
            dato1 = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
            System.out.print("¿Hace cuanto tiempo dono sangre?(1er Paciente):");
            dato2 = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();

            if (dato1 >= 8 && dato2 > 60) {
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("El 1er paciente a pasado el filtro");
                System.out.print("La muestra de sangre a sido tomada (teclee 1 = OK, 2 = NO): ");
                dato3 = scan.nextInt();

                if (dato3 == 1)   
                    System.out.println("El donante puede pasar a la sala de donación");
                else if (dato3 == 2)
                    System.out.println("El donante no es apto para la donación");
            } else {
                System.out.println("1er paciente no pasa el filtro");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int cantUsuarios;
        String nombre;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.print("Cantidad de personas a registrar: ");
            cantUsuarios = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
        } while (cantUsuarios > 5);

        regisNom(cantUsuarios);
    }
}
```

Comment: *por que al ser de tipo vid,estos se ejecutan por separado* -> Significa esto que si fuesen de tipo String (en realidad, que devuelvan un String, los métodos siempre son de tipo Method), sí podría intercalarlos? Tal cual están hechos, el resultado sería el mismo. El tipo que devuelva un método no implica que no vaya a ejecutar el bucle que lleva dentro!

Comment: hago hincapié a los métodos  que realizo el usuario,mas no en general,sus métodos conllevan prints, por lo que si se usaran intercalados en un bucle generaría un exceso de prints innecesarios,,los metodos que devuelven arreglos,String int...etc  son mas eficientes de usar en un bucle intercalados,pero un metodo void tambien puedes usarse de esa manera,aunque dependera del contenido que tenga